# Meta tag getting stripped off in AMP List/Mustache

Tags: amp-html, meta-tags, amp-list

I am trying to add ItemList MicroData for Schema but the Meta tag is getting stripped off in the amp-list/mustache.
Here's the code I am using for Microdata:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemList">
    <span itemprop="name"><?php $title; ?></span>
    <link itemprop="itemListOrder" href="https://schema.org/ItemListOrderDescending" />
    <amp-list height="100" width="auto" load-more="auto" src="https://www.flixwatch.co/stagin/list-schema/?post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" binding="no">
       <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
            <meta itemprop="position" content="{{rank}}"/>
            <div itemprop="url">{{url}}</div>
        </div>
       </template> 
    </amp-list>
</div>
```

But in [the output](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=lSysHk1EJGDReuSxjJIhxA), the meta tag is getting stripped.

Here's [an example](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=lSysHk1EJGDReuSxjJIhxA), how it should look.

I have tried adding the {{position}} in Div instead of meta tag but it's not valid as per the rich results test either. Any idea, how to get it working?

Comment: You have used amp-optimizer for this link: https://www.flixwatch.co/stagin/lists/20-best-imdb-rated-hindi-movies-and-tv-shows-on-netflix-russia/
What happens when you use the non-optimized version (the source page that was optimized)?
That will help us determine if this is an amp-optimzer issue.

Comment: It's a WP site and I am using the AMP Plugin, not sure how to disable the Optimizer.

Comment: Here's the AMP Support thread, where I was recommended to post here - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/json-ld-markup-with-amp-list-mustache/

Comment: IMHO this is a bug in `amp-optimizer`. Recommend that you post the example here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues